# Registering a new user overwrites current user session - why?

Tags: c#, servicestack

I've come across an issue when registering new users with my app. The behaviour looks to be by design, but I don't understand why.

My problem is as follows (and I know it's a bit of an edge case):

- User browses to my site's login page in two separate tabs in the same browser.
- In the first tab, the user logs in and is correctly redirected to my home page.
- In the second tab, the user follows my signup logic (which doesn't require any kind of page refresh, it's all done with client side code that culminates in a jQuery AJAX POST to the built in ServiceStack RegistrationService's /register endpoint)

Instead of creating a new user, the second user's details overwrite that of the logged in user's UserAuth record, and the first user can no longer log in.

Looking at the code in ServiceStack.ServiceInterface.Auth.RegistrationService, this behaviour appears to be 100% intentional:

```
var session = this.GetSession();
var newUserAuth = ToUserAuth(request);
var existingUser = UserAuthRepo.GetUserAuth(session, null);

var registerNewUser = existingUser == null;
var user = registerNewUser
            ? this.UserAuthRepo.CreateUserAuth(newUserAuth, request.Password)
            : this.UserAuthRepo.UpdateUserAuth(existingUser, newUserAuth, request.Password);
```

Once the first user is logged in, the session cookie for that user gets sent with the registration request, causing the existingUser variable in the code above to be populated with the UserAuth for that user, which is then updated with the registering user details.

Can anyone explain why the code's been written in this way? And is there any way around it without replacing the RegistrationService with my own implementation?

Comment: That is pretty weird. Now that I think about it, most sites do require you to sign out before you can register an account though. Maybe that could be a workaround for you?

Comment: Not really - if you stay in a single tab, you would have to log out before you can get back to the registration screen, but if the user has the site open in multiple tabs it becomes hard to enforce that on the client side. Ideally I'd be preventing it server side, but this would involve replacing the built in ServiceStack registration pieces with my own and I wanted to understand the reasoning behind the existing code first.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is the feature that lets you to auto-merge different Auth Providers into the same account in ServiceStack.

Comment: Thanks. We see that if you register multiple times with different OAuth providers that have the same email addresses, the accounts get merged and this is definitely the behaviour we need. But the auto-merging of new registrations with a currently logged in user is causing us problems - is there any way of preventing this, short of creating our own registration service?

Comment: There's some hooks in RegisterService like a static ValidateFn where you can run custom logic at the start of the Registration request and a RegistrationValidator you can override, but don't be afraid of customizing a local copy of [RegistrationService](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack/blob/master/src/ServiceStack.ServiceInterface/Auth/RegistrationService.cs) and customizing it to suit your needs - it's a far better option than trying to getting the default impl to support all use-cases.

Comment: @mythz, I'm going to end up creating my own copy of RegistrationService as you suggested because for my application, I need to restrict account creation to admins and disallow it if not logged in. But wouldn't it be more RESTful to update the existing user on a PUT and create a new user on a POST? I was shocked to discover that this wasn't the default impl.

Comment: @MattWelch Shocked? You can use either and this supports both, `PUT` is for updating a resource (like a document) at the specified url which isn't what happens nor is it 100% idempotent so `POST` is preferred, which also happens to be more practical since it's supported in HTML Forms. You can also add Request Filters for what you want otherwise using your own service does offer greater control.

Comment: Ahh I see. I guess I was thinking of the user record as a 'resource,' and `POSTing` was definitely updating the logged-in user. It appeared idempotent at first glance, aside from the LastModifiedDate. And perhaps in my somewhat simple use case, it is. In any event, I sheepishly realized I can make it work easily without creating my own service anyway if I just make the `POST` call from the client not pass credentials when I want to create a new user rather than update the logged in user. Thanks for the explanation!